# How to exclude super class properties using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class:

```java
public class User extends Body {
    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String emailId;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I want to exclude `Body` class properties with Jackson mapper because I get an error.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = new User;
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

How I can convert object to JSON with excluding all extended or implementation class? I need convert only `User` class without `Body`

My super class has many public method like this:

```java
public final Enumeration method(String email) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error");
}

public final Object method(String name) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Using `@JsonView` annotation**

Jackson library has `@JsonView` annotation which allows to provide different views of the serialized class.

You need to create a class describing different views like this:

```java
public class Views {
    public interface Base {}  // view of Base class properties
    public interface Child {} // view of Child class properties (i.e. User)
}
```

Then you mark up the fields/getters in the base `Body` class with `@JsonView(Views.Base.class)`:

```java
public class Body {
    @JsonView(Views.Base.class)
    private int foo;

    @JsonView(Views.Base.class)
    public String getBar() {
        return "bar";
    }

    // other getters/setters
}
```

The `User` class can be marked at class level:

```java
@JsonView(Views.Child.class)
public class User extends Body {
    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String email;

    // getters/setters
}
```

And when serializing with `ObjectMapper` you set its writer up to use specific view `writerWithView`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();//

User user = new User(1, "Jack", "jack@company.com");

String json = mapper.writerWithView(Views.Child.class).writeValueAsString(user);

System.out.println("custom view: " + json);  
System.out.println("full   view: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
```

Output:

```
custom view: {"userId":1,"name":"Jack","email":"jack@company.com"}
full   view: {"foo":0,"userId":1,"name":"Jack","email":"jack@company.com","bar":"bar"}
```

---

**2. Using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation**

It is also possible to customize the view of the child class by ignoring its parent class' properties:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"foo", "bar"})
public class User extends Body {
    private Integer userId;
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

Then there's no need to configure the writer `ObjectMapper` instance:

```java
System.out.println("base class fields ignored: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
```

Output:

```
base class fields ignored: {"userId":1,"name":"Jack","email":"jack@company.com"}
```

---

**3. Configure `ObjectMapper` to set custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`**

It is also possible to configure the `ObjectMapper` instance to set a custom annotation introspector to completely ignore properties belonging to the parent `Body` class:

```java
// imports for Jackson v.2.x
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember;
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
// imports for Jackson v.1.9
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedMember;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;

class IgnoreBodyClassIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(final AnnotatedMember member) {
        return member.getDeclaringClass() == Body.class || super.hasIgnoreMarker(member);
    }
}
```

Configure `ObjectMapper` and serialize `User` without any code changes to `Body` and `User`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .setAnnotationIntrospector(new IgnoreBodyClassIntrospector());

User user = new User(3, "Nobody", "nobody@company.com");

System.out.println("no base class fields: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
```

Output:

```
no base class fields: {"userId":3,"name":"Nobody","email":"nobody@company.com"}
```

Comment: I can't change Body class. Also Body class is not POJO it' have many public methods

Comment: @ValdyB, if `Body` is not a POJO, how does it interfere with `User` serialization?  If `Body` contains some fields/getters, can you add `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to the subclass `User` then?

Comment: Body class have 1000 public methods so Jacson are trying serialize this and got error. Also I can't user @JsonIgnoreProperties because I have dynamic and huge Body class

Comment: @ValdyB, I added another option to completely disable serialization of the properties belonging to the super `Body` class using custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector `

Comment: Have you tried to update the imports to refer `org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.*` in your Jackson v.1.9 instead of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.*` for Jackson v.2.x?

Comment: Though, it would be better to migrate to Jackson v.2.x because the latest v.1.9.13 was updated back in Jul 2013.

Comment: Yap, but I can't update this. Btw last option is working!